# Explain in SO FAQ concept of accepting answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, meta-faq

I see lots of folks on SO that ask tons of questions and never bother to even accept a single one.

I don't think they're all creeps—but I can't find any explanation in the SO FAQ where I could point them to, to explain how the concept of "accepting the answer" works.

This might be so self-evident to most of us—but to some, it seems quite foreign. Could the SO team add a section to the FAQ "How and why to accept answers?" and maybe even post a screenshot or two for those who claim they don't speak enough English to understand how to accept an answer? A picture is worth more than a 1'000 words—and it's true in *any* language! :-)

**UPDATE**: it would be really nice to have a link to this post on the SO FAQ page at https://stackoverflow.com/faq. People might read that page—I doubt they'll read anything else...

Comment: Does the big thumbs up image on the post linked by Diago help?

Comment: @random: it does! I'll remember that link and use it in the future, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already in the official FAQ here: [Accepting Answers, What is it all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about).

All the FAQs on all the sites point back to the FAQ tag on Meta in this regard.

There is very little that can be done about the drive by askers however, and the acceptance rate has slowly started to build awareness around the issue. Over time the more regular users are the more accepting of answers will happen.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad there's no link from the official SO FAQ to this post!