# The Site FAQ Should Graphically Show How to Accept an Answer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, accepted-answer

This is related to [Explain in SO FAQ concept of accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24827/explain-in-so-faq-concept-of-accepting-answers), but is a more specific feature request.

Please add a paragraph to https://stackoverflow.com/faq showing that one accepts an answer by clicking the check mark. I've seen posts from people who really didn't know that's what the symbol meant - perhaps it doesn't mean "yes" in all cultures?

You might also show a picture of a user block with low accepted answers, and show the relationship between the two.

On the site, I drive users towards reading the FAQ. It would be good if the necessary information were right in the document, and not just links to another site they don't have time to read.

Comment: There's a pretty in depth explanation of accepting on [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/) but I think adding this to the FAQ would be an excellent idea. Maybe an animated GIF with some freehand circles?

Comment: Not in the FAQ, but on the new about page.

Comment: @casperOne: please post a link to the about page, for completeness, and a link to the announcement and/or discussion about this change. I'm loving it, but have a suggestion.

Comment: @JohnSaunders http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163254/140951, I'm pretty sure you can find the about page fairly easy on your own. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be onto something here; Wikipedia has [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark) to say:

> In some European countries<sup>[citation needed]</sup> (e.g., Finland  and Sweden), and in Japan, the tick can be used as an error mark and indicates "no" rather than "yes".

Wouldn't that be funny, if some people are looking at the check mark thinking it means "wrong answer."

Comment: So that explains that accepted answer with 10 downvotes! (btw, I'm not voting you up because your rep is at 666 :) )

Comment: In a cosmic twist of fate, I hit the cap at 666, so I'm running in d[a]emon mode for at least the next hour and a half. :P

Comment: would you like a downvote to save your soul?

Comment: @Michael: I sold my soul *years* ago, you'd only be wasting your own rep!